# Convert toUSD(amount) function to prototype function. How?

Tags: typescript, deno

I have the following function that works fine.

```
function toUSD(amount): string {
  // RETURN number in $0.00 format
  return new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  }).format(amount);
};
```

**I use it like this:**

```
console.log(toUSD(123)); // output = $123.00
```

**What would I need to change to use it like this?**

```
console.log((123).toUSD()); // output = $123.00
```

Comment: Don't create a new instance of `Intl.NumberFormat` for every invocation — instead, create a single instance outside of the function (at the top level) and then reuse it: `const usdFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(...args); const formattedAmount = usdFormatter.format(amount);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should not use input parameters to pass the value. You have to refer to the current number using `this`:

```js
function toUSD(this: number): string {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD"
  }).format(this);
};
```

Then you can assign it to `Number.prototype` as also suggested by Ximaz' answer:

```
Number.prototype.toUSD = toUSD;
```

After that, you can call it like `(123).toUSD()` which outputs *$123.00*.

Comment: So no need to create an interface like some of the examples I've found?

Comment: Depends if you like autocompletion in your IDE I guess.

Comment: @suchislife If you only want the functionality, then no. If you want TypeScript to recognize that function everywhere, you can [modify the global module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html) and add that function declaration to the `Number` interface (similar to what the example there does for `String`).

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way to use the prototype thing would be like so :

```js
function toUSD(this: number) { ... }     // Your declaration

Number.prototype.toUSD = toUSD // Assigns the prototype to Number class

console.log((123).toUSD());    // output = $123.00
```

By looking at the solution I found out mine isn't working because I was not aware of the `this` keyword, my bad, I learned something too lol.

Unfortunatelly the output on my computer is `$NaN` but the fact that it actually displays something means that the pototype's call worked.

(Judging by the solving answer, it's because I forgot the `this` keyword, mb)